# Ошибка: E2010 Incompatible types: 'TStringList' and 'string'

Tags: delphi

```
page:=idhttp1.Get(urllist.Strings[i]);
```

не могу понять где ошибка. вроде бы типы верные

```
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(78): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TStringList' and 'string'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

а **page** у вас **String** или **StringList** ?

Comment: всё нашёл в чём ошибка, именно в типе page

Comment: @Никола: тогда отметьте ответ как верный. (птичка под количеством голосов)

Comment: видимо, впадлу. жаль